# How to Save Remote Image URL to AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to read a remote image url which is shown via  component, and what I want is to save that remote image to AsyncStorage in base64 string format so the next time it would just load the cache. anyone have ideas on how to execute this?

Comment: I think you should consider storing it on the file system instead using react-native-fs